HTML form data wong get passed to the flask backend
hello everyone Im trying to send data from a HTML form to a flask backend file and its really simple
the html file contains a simple form that has only one text input and a submit button.
this is the html code:
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="sign-form" method="POST">
      <input type="text" id="sign-username">
      <input type="submit">
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>

plain and simple
and the flask code:
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def home():
        sign_user = None  # Initialize sign_user (optional)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            try:
                sign_user = request.form['sign-username']
                print(f"Received sign-user: {sign_user}")  # Print the retrieved value
            except KeyError:
                print(f"Error: Username field not found in form data.{request.form}")
        return render_template("test.html", sign_user=sign_user)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)

the problem is that the data in sign-username wont get passed to the flask file.
what can cause the problem?
the post request will be send but the data wont reach the flask file and when i print the request.form its output is ImmutableMultiDict([])? both files are running on the local host http://127.0.0.1:5000

You have to assign a name attribute for the input field. The user input in the form fields can be retrieved from the dictionary form using the value of the name attribute.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="sign-form" method="POST">
      <input type="text" id="sign-username" name="sign-username">
      <input type="submit">
   </form>
</body>
</html>

